# BeagleBone Black ADC Freezes

Tags: beagleboneblack, adc

I am using the BeagleBone Black SBC flashed with the July 2015 debian image and attempting to utilize the on board ADC to measure voltage values. I am aware of there are issues with the sysfs adc kernel drivers that cause the virtual files containing the ADC values for each been to lock resulting in a "resource temporarily unavailable" error. To circumvent this I am attempting to make use of libpruio and the PRU's to read the ADC values. However a similar issue occurs. The ADC value freezes and will not update. Closing the program and re-running it causes the program to also freeze (sort of). The only solution being a reboot.

So the question is Two-fold: 
1) Has anyone with experience using the PRU's with libpruio and the BeagleBone Black ever encountered this issue and if so what was your solution?

2) Does anyone know a way to actually USE the on board ADC on the BeagleBone black (including a different PRU library)? So far as I can tell its is barely functional.. All methods I have seen to use it are riddled with completely breaking errors. It seems that the BeagleBone as is is just completely in capable of useful ADC.

Basic code to access ADC w/ libpruio:

```
    system("echo PRUSSDRV > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots");
    PruIo *io = pruio_new(0, 0x98, 0, 1);
    if (io->Errr)
    {
            printf("Initialisation failed (%s)\n", io->Errr);
    }

    if(pruio_config(io, 0, 0x1FE, 0, 4, 0))
    {
            printf("Config failed (%s)\n", io->Errr);
    }

    adc_raw = io->Value[6];
```

Further code can be provided as requested. In addition the problem is more prevalent when reading from an external device rather than having a voltage divider trim pot circuit using VDD_ADC, GND_ADC and AIN#.

The external source does not exceed 1.8v (ADC in pins are tolerant up to 1.8v).

Thank you in advance for your thoughts.

EDIT: Upon further experimentation I believe part of the issue is attempting to output a PWM signal while simultaneously reading ADC values. The program seems to fail only when PWM signal is being output.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Solutions? Thanks again in advance.

UPDATE: I am trying to use the PWM to drive a motor system and the ADC to read output voltage. The issue seems to occur only when the motors themselves are running regardless of whether the output is connected to the board or not. Not just when the PWM signal is output.

If I cut power to the motors and the board still outputs PWM it works fine.

If I power the motors and do NOT have the output motor connected to the ADC, but instead have the ADC pins connected to a separate trim pot using VDD_ADC the ADC freezes.

If I power the motors and do have the ADC connected to the output motor the ADC also freezes.

So it seems to be an issue with the motors actually running... Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: All the userspace libraries on the BeagleBone simply read the file in a loop up to X times - if there's an error catch it and try again, if not then return the value (yes, someone really needs to update the kernel driver...). If this method is not an acceptable way to "actually USE the on board ADC" for you, can you explain why? What's your application? What sample rate do you need?

Comment: The biggest issue is that no error is returned at all. When reading via sysfs files the value simply returns an erroneous value like "-127094687" or some nonsense. Then when attempting to access the AIN system files in /sys/devices/ocp.*/helper.*/AIN# with like cat, the message returned is "resource temporarily unavailable". 

When using the PRU's the program will simply hold a value that ceases to update. Closing the program and rerunning it the program just stalls. Nothing happens and no error messages. I have to force quit the program.

Comment: What I mean by actually use the on board ADC is that because of the sysfs issue trying to use the boards ADC via that method is not feasible for any project since obviously it breaks.... And since the PRU's are now doing something similar (holding a value w/out updating) that approach is also not feasible. That is neither one actually works... All other ADC projects using the BeagleBone are just projects where people essentially just said hang it and used a sensor with built in ADC or an external ADC like the MCP3008. So I am curious if anyone has actually managed to use the on board ADC.

Comment: I use it often - take a look at the code in PyBBIO that does it: https://github.com/graycatlabs/PyBBIO/blob/master/bbio/platform/beaglebone/adc.py#L48-L57 - I've been using it for years and never once had a failed read with it able to try up to 5 times.

Comment: @AlexHiam ): How? I stopped using the python libraries and moved on to C because I thought there was an issue with PyBBIO. Using that library it would return an erroneous value and I would wind up with the same issues where the AIN files are perma-locked requiring a reboot.

Comment: If there is an issue I don't know about - if something isn't working for you in PyBBIO open an issue (https://github.com/graycatlabs/PyBBIO/issues/new) and I'll take a look